# Confused about the increment and decrement operators in c or c++. What is the actual logic behind pre-increment or pre-decrement

Tags: c++

```
int a = 3;
cout << ++a << a++ << ++a << a++ << endl;
```

The answer of this code snippet is 7573 on codeblocks::mingw. What i got till now is that post increment goes in the right way but the preincrement has some different logic. The last value of last preincrement will be same for all preincrements. Can anyone tell me what actually happens there with ++a.

And one more thing the code needs to be solved from Right to left.
Thanks for any answer.

Comment: This is not C...

Comment: While the dupe link is about C, I'm fairly sure it's the same in C++ (before C++17, I'm unsure afterwards).

Comment: "the code needs to be solved from Right to left."  - huh?

Comment: reopened - the suggested duplicate was a different language question that is mostly not applicable here

Comment: M.M's answer is good. But I think you haven't learnt that much. If you are a beginner, avoid this usage. I mean, your code is involved in 2 questions: 1. difference between `i++` and `++i`, 2. *order of evaluation*.

Answer (score 6):

[Since C++17:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> In a shift operator expression `E1<<E2` and `E1>>E2`, every value computation and side-effect of `E1` is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of `E2`

So the output is well-defined and should be `4466`.

Prior to C++17 the code caused undefined behaviour [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/).  Your output suggests that you are using an old compiler (or invoking the compiler in old mode).

Comment: Question is about function calls not shift operators overloaded `operator<<` .

Comment: @RichardCritten overloaded operators have the same sequencing rules as built-in operators (since C++17)